Inverse Fourier transform of impedance
I am studying a scattering problem from an imperfect conductor in time domain. Therefore i utilize the Leontovich boundary condition which is written as $E_t=Z_s\mathbf n\times H_t$ where $E_t$ is the total tangnetial electric field on the boundary, $H_t$ is the total tangential magnetic field on the boundary and $Z_s$ is the surface impedance of the imperfect conductor which is given by $Z_s=\sqrt{i \omega \mu_0/\sigma}$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the conductor. In order to simulate the time domain scattering i need among other calculations, the inverse Fourier Transform of $Z_s=\sqrt{i \omega \mu_0/\sigma}$ (impedance in time domain). I tried everything but it is impossible to find a solution. I tried even mathematica but the transform that it calculates yields negative values of time domain impedance which is unphysical! Does anyone can help!

see page 11, Eq 1.13 without derivation, in Stumpf: Time-Domain Electromagnetic Reciprocity in Antenna Modeling: $Z(t)=\sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial  t} [I_0(\alpha t /2)e^{-\alpha t/2} 1(t)]$ where $\alpha = \sigma/\epsilon_1$ and $1(t)$  is the unit step function.

Hyportnex's comment is rather the inverse Laplace transform of:
$$
Z = \sqrt{\frac{i\omega\mu}{\sigma+i\omega\epsilon}}
$$
Setting with no loss of generality $\epsilon=\mu=\sigma=1$, it is just the inverse Laplace transform of:
$$
Z = \sqrt{\frac{s}{1+s}} \\
\mathcal L^{-1}Z=\frac{e^{-t/2}}2(I_1(t/2)-I_0(t/2))+\delta(t)
$$
using the principal branch so that it is analytic in the half plane $\Re s>0$ for causal signal in time domain.
For your original problem, just set $\epsilon=0$ or compute directly:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal L^{-1}[\sqrt s] &= \int_{0^+-i\infty}^{0^++i\infty}\sqrt se^{st}\frac{ds}{2\pi i} \\
&= t^{-3/2}\int_{H}\sqrt se^s\frac{ds}{2\pi i} \\
&= \frac1{\Gamma(-1/2)t^{3/2}} \\
&= -\frac2{\sqrt{\pi t^3}} 
&& (=\chi_+^{-3/2}(t))\\
\end{align}
$$
with $H$ the usual Hankel contour about the negative real halfline, and the final result is understood as the Hadamard finite part as described for example in "Homogeneous_distribution". Alternatively use the table of usual Fourier/Laplace transforms and take the (distributional) derivatives. Note that this is just the large time asymptotics of the first formula (with special care in treating the origin).
In fact, for numerical simulations, setting $\epsilon\neq0$ (but small) might be a good idea to regularize the behavior for small times.
